# Неправильно парсится double из JSON

Tags: json, double

Не могу понять в чем причина неверного Парсинга, при чем небольшие числа нормально парсятся.

[image: Так парится double]
[image: Так приходит с сервера]

Подобные случаи были, спасала строка:
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().jsonConfig(jsonConfig().numberReturnType(DOUBLE));

Comment: так полностью корректный парсинг же!

Comment: На всякий случай: E11 означает число, которое шло до этого умножить на 10 в 11 степени. Аналогично Е5 означает умножить на 10 в пятой степени.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Это конечно здорово, но мне хотелось бы переменную balance использовать сразу. Возможно ли что-то сделать что бы парилось сразу к виду как в json?

Comment: Это всего лишь форма вывода для чтения человеком, внутри (для компьютера) нет никакой разницы между тем, что Вы видите и тем, что в Json. Используйте сколько угодно))

Comment: Хорошо. Как мне использовать это значение? Метод преобразования написать?

Comment: Под использовать Вы понимаете вывод на экран? Для всего остального, как я и писал, оно и так отлично работает.

Comment: Использую для сравнения UI элемента в тесте. Это значение будет приводиться к типу String и сравниваться

Comment: Для этого лучше сконвертировать строку в `Double` и сравнивать уже числа (не забывая про хитрости внутреннего представления) Либо используйте `String.format()` для преобразования в строку (но тут будут свои нюансы)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Мне помогло это String.format("%.2f", balance)